# I have JQuery Toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, toggle

I have a jquery toggle button and when I click on it, a google map display below. But I don't want to use toggle event. I want to display google map when I open the website (without toggle). How can I remove this event? Here are my js codes.

```
 __mapButton.unbind("click").on("click", __renderGoogleMap);

 this.renderGoogleMap = __renderGoogleMap;
 var __renderGoogleMap = function (e) {
     if (__listData && __listData.TotalResultCount > 0) {
  __mapButton.toggleClass("opened");

  var __isVisible = $(__mapID).is(':visible');

  if (__isVisible) {
    $(__mapID).show();
    if (!__isRendered) {
      $(__mapID).empty();
    }
    __mapButton.text(__mapButtonText.show);
  }
  else {
    $(__mapID).show();
    __mapButton.text(__mapButtonText.show);
  }

  if (__isMapCreated) return 0;

  __isMapCreated = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your code outside of the on click function, but inside of a document on ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 this.renderGoogleMap = __renderGoogleMap;
 var __renderGoogleMap = function (e) {
     if (__listData && __listData.TotalResultCount > 0) {
  __mapButton.toggleClass("opened");

  var __isVisible = $(__mapID).is(':visible');

  if (__isVisible) {
    $(__mapID).show();
    if (!__isRendered) {
      $(__mapID).empty();
    }
    __mapButton.text(__mapButtonText.show);
  }
  else {
    $(__mapID).show();
    __mapButton.text(__mapButtonText.show);
  }

  if (__isMapCreated) return 0;

  __isMapCreated = 1;
}
```

Comment: If you found this post helpful, please remember to select it as the answer :)